# window.location Open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, window.open, window.location

I want to be able to open the links in a new tab but I'm unsure what changes to make to get it to work. I have see other questions on here regarding `window.open` but I don't have that in this code to work with, only `window.location`.  I have changed the only instance to window.open but the link doesn't work at that point. I think that I may have to change the linking section to accept the `window.location` but I'm not sure how.

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function carousel(params){
if(!(params.width>0&&isFinite(params.width)))params.width=100;
if(!(params.height>0&&isFinite(params.height)))params.height=100;
if(!(params.sides>2&&isFinite(params.sides)))params.sides=4;
if(!(params.steps>0&&params.steps<100&&isFinite(params.steps)))params.steps=20;
if(!(params.speed>0&&isFinite(params.speed)))params.speed=8;
if(!      (params.image_border_width>=0&&isFinite(params.image_border_width)))params.image_border_width=0;
if(isFinite(params.id)||!params.id)params.id='bad_id_given_'+Math.random();

document.write("<div style='position:relative;overflow:hidden;' id='"+params.id.replace(/[\r\n\t ]+/g,'_')+"'></div>");
var cdiv=document.getElementById(params.id.replace(/[\r\n\t ]+/g,'_'))
cdiv.style.width=params.width+'px';
cdiv.style.height=params.height+'px';
cdiv.style.border=params.border;
cdiv.style.position='relative';
cdiv.style.overflow='hidden';
cdiv.title=params.id;

var counter=0,spinning=true,interval=Math.floor(60000/params.sides/params.steps/params.speed)-5;
interval=isNaN(interval)?200:interval;
var img_position=[],images=[],img_dimension=[];
var img_index=params.images.length+1,img_index_cap=2*params.images.length;
var faces=Math.ceil(params.sides/2), dimension, direction;

function init(){
if(params.direction=="left" || params.direction=="right"){
  direction=params.direction;
  dimension="width";
  }
else if(params.direction=="top" || params.direction=="bottom"){
  direction=params.direction;
  dimension="height";
  }
else {
  direction="left";
  dimension="width";
  }      
cdiv.style[dimension]=params[dimension]/(params.size_mode=='image'?Math.sin(Math.PI/params.sides):1)+'px';
var img=new Image();
img.style.position='absolute';
img.style[direction]='10000px';
img.style.width=params.width-2*params.image_border_width+'px';
img.style.height=params.height-2*params.image_border_width+'px';
img.style.border=(params.image_border_width||0)+'px solid '+params.image_border_color;

for(var i=0;i<params.images.length;i++){
  images[i]=img.cloneNode(true);
  images[i].src=params.images[i];
  if(params.links&&params.links[i]&&params.links[i]!=''){
    images[i].onclick=new Function("window.location='"+params.links[i]+"'");
    images[i].style.cursor=document.all?'hand':'pointer';
    }
  if(params.titles&&params.titles[i]&&params.titles[i]!='')
    images[i].title=params.titles[i];
  images[i+params.images.length]=images[i];
  if(params.images.length==faces)
    images[i+2*params.images.length]=images[i];
  cdiv.appendChild(images[i]);
  }

var face_size=params.size_mode=='image'?params[dimension]:params[dimension]*Math.sin(Math.PI/params.sides);
var face_offset=params[dimension]*Math.cos(Math.PI/params.sides)/(params.size_mode=='image'?Math.sin(Math.PI/params.sides):1)/2-.5;
var pi_piece=2*Math.PI/params.steps/params.sides;
for(i=0;i<=params.steps*faces;i++){
  img_dimension[i]=face_size*Math.sin(pi_piece*i);
  img_position[i]=(i<params.steps*params.sides/2)?Math.floor(params[dimension]/2/(params.size_mode=='image'?Math.sin(Math.PI/params.sides):1)-face_offset*Math.cos(pi_piece*i)-img_dimension[i]/2)+'px':'10000px';
  img_dimension[i]=img_dimension[i]-2*params.image_border_width>1?Math.ceil(img_dimension[i])-2*params.image_border_width+'px':'1px';
  }
}
init();

cdiv.rotate = function(){
setTimeout('document.getElementById("'+cdiv.id+'").rotate()',interval);
if(!spinning) return;
if(++counter>=params.steps){
  counter=0;
  if(++img_index>=img_index_cap)
    img_index=params.images.length;
  }
images[img_index-faces].style[direction]='20000px';
for(var i=faces-1;i>=0;i--){
  images[img_index-i].style[direction]=img_position[counter+i*params.steps];
  images[img_index-i].style[dimension]=img_dimension[counter+i*params.steps];
  }
}
cdiv.onmouseover=function(){
spinning=false;
}
cdiv.onmouseout=function(){
spinning=true;
}
setTimeout('document.getElementById("'+cdiv.id+'").rotate()',200);
}
</script>
</head>
```

**Then in the body:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
carousel({id:'YOUR_ID_HERE',
      border:'',
      size_mode:'image',
      width:138,
      height:225,
      sides:11,
      steps:44,
      speed:2,
      direction:'left',
      images:['https://genericlink.com/image1.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image2.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image3.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image4.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image5.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image6.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image7.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image8.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image9.jpg',
              'https://genericlink.com/image10.jpg'],
      links: ['https://genericlink.com/page1',
              'https://genericlink.com/page2',
              'https://genericlink.com/page3',
              'https://genericlink.com/page4',
              'https://genericlink.com/page5',
              'https://genericlink.com/page6',
              'https://genericlink.com/page7',
              'https://genericlink.com/page8',
              'https://genericlink.com/page9',
              'https://genericlink.com/page10'],
      titles:['1',
              '2',
              '3',
              '4',
              '5',
              '6',
              '7',
              '8',
              '9',
              '10'],
      image_border_width:1,
      image_border_color:'#ffffff'
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, bu you don't even understand you own code, and expect us to understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant just replace `window.location` with `window.open`. It's syntax is slightly different.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Try replacing:

```
images[i].onclick=new Function("window.location='"+params.links[i]+"'");
```

With:

```
images[i].onclick=new Function("window.open("'+params.links[i]+'")");
```

Comment: It opened a new tab but... `file:///C:/Users/xxxxx2/Desktop/+params.links[i]+`  That's what the output is and I get a Page Not Found.

Comment: I used the wrong quote marks in my example. If you just copied and pasted it, try again with my edit.

Comment: images[i].onclick=new Function("window.open('" + params.links[i] + "')");